# Upload image, Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple create post function that and i want to create a post when i fill the title,content and image:

[image]

But when i upload an image the progress bar fills, the image is uploaded to firebase but it doesn't let me create a post and when i test it in console it has this error:

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../core/auth.service';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';



import { PostService } from '../post.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './post-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-dashboard.component.css']
})
export class PostDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string;
  image: string = null;
  content: string;

  buttonText: string = "Create Post"

  uploadPercent: Observable<number>
  downloadURL: Observable<string>

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private postService: PostService, 
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  uploadImage(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const path = `posts/${file.name}`
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
      return alert('only image files')
    } else {
      const task = this.storage.upload(path, file)
      this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges()
      console.log('Image Uploaded!')
      this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => this.image = url)
    }
  }

  createPost() {
    const data = {
      author: this.auth.authState.displayName || this.auth.authState.email,
      authorId: this.auth.currentUserId,
      content: this.content,
      image: this.image,
      published: new Date(),
      title: this.title
    };
    this.postService.create(data)
    this.title = ''
    this.content = ''
    this.image = ''
    this.buttonText = 'Post Created!'
    setTimeout(() => (this.buttonText = "Create Post"), 3000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like the error says, `this.downloadURL` is undefined, make sure it's initialized before you use it